# Does android support PBAP bluetooth profile?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm starting to develop a kind of car infotainment system based on android. The idea is to create a cover ROM for the stock android using a development board.

At first step I'm just playing with basic elemnts, and developing something like a launcher. But now I must starting with something more difficult, bluetooth.

I've done an app based on the bluetooth chat example, so I've got some basics on bluetooth. But still isn't enough for this.

As I see, the bluetooth profile that uses to manage the phone's phone book to see it on the car, is the Phone Book Access Profile (PBAP) which it seems that android doesn't support it. On the developers page:

```
Known Indirect Subclasses:
BluetoothA2dp, BluetoothGatt, BluetoothGattServer, BluetoothHeadset, BluetoothHealth
```

But now a days, there a few car companies including android on cars, so, there must be some way to achieve this.

Does someone have the knowledge about this to let me see some light?

Answer (score 1):

Up ! Same question...
Maybe investigate those kind of links below :

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ee0b3e9/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothPbap.java

But I don't really know how to use it for now... still missing some stuff, like the source of the unknown IBluetoothPbap class, at line 71.

JB

Answer (score 0):

1. connect bt over Pbap using api in frameworks/base/core/java/android/bluetooth
2. use frameworks/base/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothPbapClient.java methods, these methods call PbapClientService.java api in packages/apps/Bluetooth/src/com/android/bluetooth/pbapclient/
3. access contacts simply through the content provider.